# Show that if f is analytic in $|z|\leq 1$, there must be some positive integer n such that $f(\frac{1}{n})\neq \frac{1}{n+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if f is analytic in $|z|\leq 1$, there must be some positive integer n such that $f(\frac{1}{n})\neq \frac{1}{n+1}$

MY SOLUTION

If $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{n+1}$, then for all points $z_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ ,
$f(z_{n})=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{z_{n}}+1}$
or $f(z_{n})=\frac{z_{n}}{1 + z_{n}}$ Because ${z_{n}}$ has an accumulation point at 0, this implies that $f(z)=\frac{z}{1+z}$ throughout its domain of analyticity which yields a contradiction since f was assumed analytic at
$z=-1$.

Can anyone help me improve it?

Comment: Your solution looks fine to me.

Comment: thanks,But it would be understandable to deliver the task, do not you need to justify anything?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. But your solution as written is fine. If you want to be nitpicky, you should point out that $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{z_n}+1}$ has a singularity at $0$, but it's removable so there aren't any serious issues here.

Comment: @BrettFrankel Or not to mention $\frac 1{\frac1{z_n}+1}$ at all and only verify that $f(z)$ coincides with $\frac z{1+z}$ for all $z=z_n$

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no; your solution is as good as it could be. (Posting this CW to remove the question from "unanswered")